# Is it possible to take different data types as input using a single variable in c++

Tags: c++, input, types

I just started learning c++ and dont know much so let me just describe the end goal first. I want to keep taking input from the user `user_input = std::cin >> value` using a loop. Then i want to end the loop as soon as the user is done with the inputs by letting the user type "done". But for this is would have to declate a variable as both `int` and `string`, which is not allowed in c++ as far as i know.While doing some reading, i came across templates and this is the best thing i managed to come up with.

```
   template<typename type>
    type input()
    {
        type value;
        std::cin >> value;
        return value;
    }
```

We can call this as `int user = in::input<>();` but i do still need to specify the data type. So is there any way to improve this to not take data type or maybe some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Read everything as strings and if the string != "done" convert it to an integer ? Use a sentinel value (like -1) instead of "done" for the end of input ? You have to get down to types somewhere. If you're just learning C++ I'd keep it simple for now...

Comment: A variable can only ever have *one* type.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But that type can be [any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)thing ;)

Comment: You can't `cin` into `std::any` though (*operator>> undefined*). You would still need to `cin` into a variable, and only then can you assign it to a `std::any` object.